# Why the speed of the video depends on the number of FPS in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, video, frame-rate

I have a code which capture screen and make a video from the screenshots using OpenCV. So if I change fps to 60 in my videoWriter object(video lasts 10 seconds or more) will play for 1 second. As I understood, higher FPS makes video faster and lower FPS makes it's slower. Could you explain for me why it works that way?

Comment: FPS = Frames per second. That says everything.

Comment: I know that, but the main problem is that when I set FPS to 60 it's much faster than the same video with FPS = 30. I don't understand why it gets faster? Could you explain please?

Comment: Because the number of frames that are contained in the video is fixed. If you change the FPS you will change the number of frames that are shown in a single second. Therefore, you will speed up the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you record a video for 4 seconds with 2 FPS. You'll record 8 frames in total:

[image]

Now suppose you double the frame rate to 4 FPS. This tells your video player to show 4 frames every second, so those 8 frames are now shown to the viewer in 2 seconds - a speed up of the video.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I understand what you mean, but problem is that when I record 10 seconds in 30 FPS, after that when I play it there is no 30FPS because it's too fast. So my 10 seconds video recorded with 30 FPS is played for 5 seconds but if I record around 14 FPS it's similar to 30 FPS by the speed. Or maybe I don't understand something, thanks in advance!

Comment: It could be helpful if you edit your question and share a sample video file, maybe one recorded in 14 FPS and one with 30